# Rig eye to empty

Tags: rigging

[image]

I want to rig the eye to pivot 001, but when I move it in pose mode.

[image: pose mode]

The other eye won't stay in place. Could someone help me? I have been stuck for about an hour.

Comment: You probably need to remove its Armature modifier, because it cumulates with the parenting to bone

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I really appreciate it. This simple issue almost make me gone mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the *Armature* modifier of your object, because it cumulates with the parenting to bone you've made (or on the contrary, keep the modifier and unparent from the bone).